# Connecting JSP to MySql in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I have my sample code here :

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 

<% 
/* Create string of connection url within specified format with machine name, port number and database name. Here machine name id localhost and database name is usermaster. */ 
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ekoh"; 

// declare a connection by using Connection interface 
Connection connection = null; 

// Load JBBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 

/* Create a connection by using getConnection() method that takes parameters of string type connection url, user name and password to connect to database. */ 
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");

// check weather connection is established or not by isClosed() method 
if(!connection.isClosed())
%>
<font size="+3" color="green"></b>
<% 
out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
connection.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){
%>
</font>
<font size="+3" color="red"></b>
<%
out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
}
%>
```

my db name is "ekoh", I used root account with no password..
Still no clue for me why it is still not working till now.. Can you give me some alternative code to run for? :)
n.b. I code JSP with tomcat and MySql in XAMPP.

Comment: First, you don't say what "not working" means. do you have an error message? Second, JSP is a *display* technology. Creating a database connection from a JSP page is a supremely bad idea - I'd suggest either finding a decent web framework or at the very least, writing a servlet to do your data access, put the results in request scope, and then forward to your jsp for *display*

Comment: For starters, the exception contains the answer. But you're suppressing/ignoring it. You should throw it or at least print/log its stacktrace.

Comment: the display is Unable to connect to database.
Still, it is not for my real project. just want to check how to connecting mysql w/ jsp.
can you give me some working code?

Answer (score 0):

What one needs to do is [download the MySQL connector jar file](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html) and then put it inside the folder path `/WEB-INF/lib` in your project folder.